# Cut a dendrogram

Tags: r, list, dendrogram, ape

I have a `dendrogram`:

```
set.seed(10)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(20*10),nrow=20,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mat)))
```

And given a depth cutoff:

I'd like to cut all branches that are to the right to that cutoff.

```
depth.cutoff <- 4.75
```

I'd like to cut all branches to the right of the dashed line:

```
plot(dend,horiz = TRUE)
abline(v=depth.cutoff,col="red",lty=2)
```

[image]

And to end up with this `dendrogram`:

[image]

The closest I got was using `ape`'s `drop.tip`, but the problem with that is if my `depth.cutoff` includes all leaves, as in this example, it returns `NULL`.

Perhaps anyone knows if and how I can delete elements from the `nested list` which represents my `dendrogram` if their `depth` is below `depth.cutoff`?

Alternatively, perhaps I can convert the `dendrogram` to a `data.frame`, which also lists the `depth` of each `node` (including leaves which will have `depth`=0), remove all rows with `depth` `<` `depth.cutoff` from that `data.frame`, and then convert that back to a `dendrogram`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` will cut the tree at a specified height. It will return a list of the `upper` and `lower` portions

```
cut(dend, h = depth.cutoff)$upper

# $upper
# 'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 5 members total, at height 5.887262 
# 
# $lower
# $lower[[1]]
# 'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 6 members total, at height 4.515119 
# 
# $lower[[2]]
# 'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 2 members total, at height 3.789259 
# 
# $lower[[3]]
# 'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 5 members total, at height 3.837733 
# 
# $lower[[4]]
# 'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 3 members total, at height 3.845031 
# 
# $lower[[5]]
# 'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 4 members total, at height 4.298743


plot(cut(dend, h = depth.cutoff)$upper, horiz = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @SymbolixAU. Do you know if there's a way to get all branches to end at the same line? Not in the plot but rather in the dend object?

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps more direct way of getting your picture is just to set the limits that you want to plot.

```
plot(dend, horiz = TRUE, xlim=c(6,4.75))
```

[image: Cropped Dendrogram]

Comment: certainly a more 'convenient' way if all the OP wants to do is plot a particular section.